# Lightlin background colors not displaying in MacOS Terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, init, plugin-lightline

Background colors in the status line (and elsewhere in vim) are not displaying. This may be because I am using someone else's Lightline config, but it looks quite different to what I am seeing.

[image: no bg colors]

My `init.vim` file:

```
call plug#begin("~/.vim/plugged")
  " Plugin Section
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plug 'peitalin/vim-jsx-typescript'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
call plug#end()
"Config Section
if (has("termguicolors"))
  set termguicolors
endif
syntax enable
let g:NERDTreeShowHidden = 1
let g:NERDTreeMinimalUI = 1
let g:NERDTreeIgnore = []
let g:NERDTreeStatusline = ''
let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'ag -g ""'
let g:lightline = {
  \ 'colorscheme': 'landscape',
    \ 'active': {
    \   'left': [ [ 'mode', 'paste' ],
    \             [ 'readonly', 'filename', 'modified', 'coc_error', 'coc_warning', 'coc_hint', 'coc_info' ] ],
    \   'right': [ [ 'lineinfo',  ],
    \              [ 'percent' ],
    \              [ 'fileformat', 'fileencoding', 'filetype'] ]
    \ },
  \ 'component_expand': {
  \   'coc_error'        : 'LightlineCocErrors',
  \   'coc_warning'      : 'LightlineCocWarnings',
  \   'coc_info'         : 'LightlineCocInfos',
  \   'coc_hint'         : 'LightlineCocHints',
  \   'coc_fix'          : 'LightlineCocFixes',
  \ }
  \ }
let g:lightline.component_type = {
\   'coc_error'        : 'error',
\   'coc_warning'      : 'warning',
\   'coc_info'         : 'tabsel',
\   'coc_hint'         : 'middle',
\   'coc_fix'          : 'middle',
\ }

let g:lightline.component_type = {
\   'coc_error'        : 'error',
\   'coc_warning'      : 'warning',
\   'coc_info'         : 'tabsel',
\   'coc_hint'         : 'middle',
\   'coc_fix'          : 'middle',
\ }

function! s:lightline_coc_diagnostic(kind, sign) abort
  let info = get(b:, 'coc_diagnostic_info', 0)
  if empty(info) || get(info, a:kind, 0) == 0
    return ''
  endif
  try
    let s = g:coc_user_config['diagnostic'][a:sign . 'Sign']
  catch
    let s = ''
  endtry
  return printf('%s %d', s, info[a:kind])
endfunction

function! LightlineCocErrors() abort
  return s:lightline_coc_diagnostic('error', 'error')
endfunction

function! LightlineCocWarnings() abort
  return s:lightline_coc_diagnostic('warning', 'warning')
endfunction

function! LightlineCocInfos() abort
  return s:lightline_coc_diagnostic('information', 'info')
endfunction

function! LightlineCocHints() abort
  return s:lightline_coc_diagnostic('hints', 'hint')
endfunction
\ }

autocmd User CocDiagnosticChange call lightline#update()
" Automaticaly close nvim if NERDTree is only thing left open
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
" Toggle
nnoremap <silent> <C-b> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
" open new split panes to right and below
set splitright
set splitbelow
" turn terminal to normal mode with escape
tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
" start terminal in insert mode
au BufEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | :startinsert | endif
" open terminal on ctrl+n
function! OpenTerminal()
  split term://bash
  resize 10
endfunction
nnoremap <c-n> :call OpenTerminal()<CR>
" use alt+hjkl to move between split/vsplit panels
tnoremap <A-h> <C-\><C-n><C-w>h
tnoremap <A-j> <C-\><C-n><C-w>j
tnoremap <A-k> <C-\><C-n><C-w>k
tnoremap <A-l> <C-\><C-n><C-w>l
nnoremap <A-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <A-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <A-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <A-l> <C-w>l

nnoremap <C-p> :FZF<CR>
let g:fzf_action = {
  \ 'ctrl-t': 'tab split',
  \ 'ctrl-s': 'split',
  \ 'ctrl-v': 'vsplit'
  \}
```

Comment: macOS terminal doesn't support termguicolors

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble), Terminal.app does not support `termguicolors`. I have found that using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com) I can have these display perfectly.

Comment: For completeness, [here](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728) is a list of terminal applications. Alacritty and Kitty are two other popular macOS ones in addition to iTerm 2.

Comment: I meant to say “terminal applications that support true colours”